# implementing group by using map reduce

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, group-by

I know that there is a groupby implementations in spark, but I am trying to understand how they work.
I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a95252823e09939b654dd425db38dadc4100bc87/python/pyspark/rdd.py).

I don't understand exactly whether it only maps the keys or does it also do a reduce operation.

How would you implement group by - using map/reduce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is kind of convoluted. But here is a stab at your intention.

Any `aggregate` function *does* require a `reduce` stage.  The `groupBy` is such an aggregate function. In fact `groupBy` is basically the *most expensive* family of aggregate functions.

AFA the code: here it shows clearly:

```
 groupByKey(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions))
```

Note that the `HashPartitioner` *always* performs a `shuffle`: so you are getting a full `reducer-side` (in map/reduce lingo) operation.

**Update** The OP asked for more details on how the `reduce` works.

Similarly to Map-Reduce the `reduce` combines the results from the `map` stage according to the configured `Partitioner` - which evaluates the key of each record and distributes to the appropriate partition according to the key. That is the `shuffle` phase.

Then the `reducer` logic would be to apply the specified `aggregate` operation - and potentially additional `having` (i.e. filters based on the aggregate conditions) and `sorting` (if they were `local` not 'total` ordering)

Comment: What does the reduce do?

Comment: @Lee I have updated the answer for more details on how `reduce` works on spark.